# How to Use workspace in incognito mode in Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: google-chrome, desktop-environments, workspaces, autohide

I want to  Create a separate  workspace for incognito work. This completely isolates it from my main workspace, making it invisible and inaccessible unless i switch to that specific workspace. It's like having a hidden basement apartment in my digital house How to do that? For example I want to use Google Chrome and Visual Studio Code at same time .I can simply Switch Between these two workspaces easily but i want to hide /isolate Chrome Workspace Unless I  want to show that Hidden Chrome Workspace I con show or hide it by coomand or By short Cut ? This is all I want But Donot Know How to do that ? **Kindly Help**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about your goal. Anyway.

Give a try to `devilspie` and/or `devilspie2`

those are utilities that

> lets you make applications start in specified workplaces, in specified sizes and placements, minimized or maximized and much more based on simple config files

They are both available via apt install.

**Note** if in you i might rely more on devilspie2 since it still has signs of being "alive"

Regarding Chrome...it has few built-in functions that allows you to have more profiles